# SPARQL group concat union

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to `GROUP_CONCAT` a `UNION` of two sets of triples.
Is this not allowed?

```sql
PREFIX bo: <https://webfiles.uci.edu/jenniyk2/businessontology#>  
SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?m2;SEPARATOR = ", ") AS ?comp)
WHERE 
{
{{SELECT  ?m2 ?c ?p
WHERE { ?c rdfs:label ?m. ?c2 rdfs:label ?m2. ?so bo:owner ?p. 
?so bo:sharesIn ?c. ?so2 bo:owner ?p. ?so2 bo:sharesIn ?c2. }
}
UNION
{SELECT  ?m2 ?c ?p
WHERE { ?c rdfs:label ?m. ?c2 rdfs:label ?m2. ?dir  bo:isPartOf ?c. 
?dir bo:isDirectedBy ?p. ?dir2 bo:isPartOf ?c2. ?dir2 bo:isDirectedBy ?p.}
}}
GROUP BY ?c
HAVING (COUNT(?m2) >1)}
```

It says there's an error in the very last line.

> `Found group. Was expecting one of : BIND, BLANK_NODE_LABEL, DECIMAL,
>    DOUBLE, FALSE, FILTER, GEO, GRAPH, INTEGER, MINUS, NIL-SYMBOL, OPTIONAL,
>    Q_IRI_REF, QNAME, QNAME_NS, SERVICE, STRING_LITERAL1, STRING_LITERAL2,
>    STRING_LITERAL_LONG1, STRING_LITERAL_LONG2, TEXTINDEX, TRUE, UNION, VALUES, 
>    VARNAME or punctuation '(', '+', '-', '.', '[', '[]', '{', '}'.`

Comment: It looks like there's a lot more query here than is necessary.  I the query isn't being automatically generated or something like that, I think you can probably make it a bit simpler.  That's not exactly the typographical problem that JeenB pointed out, but it might have made it easier to catch in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses should be *outside* the `WHERE` clause, not inside it as they currently are. To make your query syntactically correct, remove the closing `}` from the last line and add it on the line above your `GROUP BY`:

```
PREFIX bo: <https://webfiles.uci.edu/jenniyk2/businessontology#>  
SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?m2;SEPARATOR = ", ") AS ?comp)
WHERE 
{
{{SELECT  ?m2 ?c ?p
WHERE { ?c rdfs:label ?m. ?c2 rdfs:label ?m2. ?so bo:owner ?p. 
?so bo:sharesIn ?c. ?so2 bo:owner ?p. ?so2 bo:sharesIn ?c2. }
}
UNION
{SELECT  ?m2 ?c ?p
WHERE { ?c rdfs:label ?m. ?c2 rdfs:label ?m2. ?dir  bo:isPartOf ?c. 
?dir bo:isDirectedBy ?p. ?dir2 bo:isPartOf ?c2. ?dir2 bo:isDirectedBy ?p.}
}}}
GROUP BY ?c
HAVING (COUNT(?m2) >1)
```

As Joshua also indicated, the query can be written a lot simpler, but this should solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 6):

Jeen Broekstra's answer identifies the typographical problem that causes your syntax error, but I think it's worth mentioning that this query can be simplified a bit, because simpler code from the beginning makes it easier to spot typos and syntax errors when they arise.  If I read it correctly, it looks like the body of the query simplifies to this:

```sql
  ?c  rdfs:label ?m .
  ?c2 rdfs:label ?m2 .
  { ?so  bo:owner ?p ;
         bo:sharesIn ?c .
    ?so2 bo:owner ?p ;
         bo:sharesIn ?c2 . }
  union
  { ?dir  bo:isPartOf ?c ;
          bo:isDirectedBy ?p .
    ?dir2 bo:isPartOf ?c2 ;
          bo:isDirectedBy ?p }
```

You're looking for a **?c** that's connected by one of two certain types of path to a **?c2**, and you want to group by **?c** and concatenate the distinct labels of **?c2**.  I see two ways that this  could be simplified further.  The first is with the use of property paths, since you don't actually use the values of many of these variables.  With property paths, the body could become:

```sql
  ?c  rdfs:label ?m .
  ?c2 rdfs:label ?m2 .
  { ?c ^bo:sharesIn/bo:owner/^bo:owner/bo:sharesIn ?c2 }
  union
  { ?c ^bo:isPartOf/bo:isDirectedBy/^bo:isDirectedBy/bo:isPartOf ?c2 }
```

As another alternative, since the *structure* of the pattern in each union alternative is similar, you could abstract a bit with **values**:

```sql
  ?c  rdfs:label ?m .
  ?c2 rdfs:label ?m2 .
  values (?sharesIn_isPartOf ?owner_isDirectedBy) {
    (bo:sharesIn bo:owner)
    (bo:isPartOf bo:isDirectedBy)
  }
  ?x  ?owner_isDirectedBy ?y  ;
      ?sharesIn_isPartOf  ?c  .
  ?x2 ?owner_isDirectedBy ?y  ;
      ?sharesIn_isPartOf  ?c2 .
```